# Jquery Validation and calling Remote functions Asp.net Razor View Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I am trying to translate a semi-old MVC2 site into a new and snazzy MVC4 site.  So far so good, and I am really only stuck on the validation part of the site.  I have a jquery function that is supposed to check for the uniqueness of a certain value, and allow the form to submit if it is indeed unique,  Otherwise it won't submit.  Also, it is only required if a certain variable is set... 'isFlagSet' if you will.  If it is, then required is true... and then you would remotely check for uniqueness.  The jquery validation function is below

```
$('#eEncId').validate({
    rules: {
        HospitalFinNumber: {
            required: function (element) {
                debugger;
                return '@isFlagSet' != 'True'; //$('AddEnc').val() === 'AddEnc';
            },
            minlength: 6,
            remote: function () {
                debugger;
                return {
                    url: '@Url.Action("ValidateHosFin", "EditEncounter")',
                    data: { hospitalFin: $('#HospitalFinNumber').val(), encflag: '@encflag' }
                };
            }
        },
        DateOfBirth: {
            required: true
        },
        AdminDate: {
            required: true
        },
        Comment: {
            required: function (element) {
                return $(element).val().length > 4000;
            },
            maxlength: 4000
        }
    },
    messages: {
        HospitalFinNumber: 'Please Enter a valid Hospital Fin number',
        DateOfBirth: 'Please enter a valid Date Of Birth',
        AdmitDate: 'Please select an Admit Date',
        Comment: 'Why dont you stop attempting to put in more than 4000 characters?  Thanks...'
    }
});
```

Seems, pretty straight forward right?  Well, It was in MVC2.  Now I am running into some logical inconsistencies (in my own feeble mind) and also it doesn't seem as though I am calling the remote function.  Even though I am getting into the remote debugger.  Am I doing something wrong?  Do I need to put a remote attribute over the Model field even though I don't use unobtrusive-ajax?  What would you guys recommend?

Comment: looks like I was missing the type argument.  I will update my post with the correct way to approach remote validation...

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though to successfully call a remote function, you need to also have the type argument in your return parameter list....

```
remote: function () {
    debugger;
    return {
        url: '@Url.Action("ValidateHosFin", "EditEncounter")',
        type: "POST",
        data: { hospitalFin: $('#HospitalFinNumber').val(), encflag: '@encflag' }
    };
}
```